# Using an ItemPresenter within a content presenter possible in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding

I'm trying to get a `ListBox` to change its back ground from a `Grid` to a user selected `Image` at the click of a `Button`.  Besides the background, the list box contains a collection of UI elements that are bound to an `ObservableCollection` via `ItemSource`, and then presented via item presenter.

Originally I had the background XML within the `ListBox`'s template, and this worked fine up until I needed to put a content presenter in there to give the user the option to selected different back grounds.

The background updates fine, it's just that none of the `ListBox` items show up.  Any idea why this is happening? Here is the code:

```
<ListBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedObject}" 
                 PreviewMouseMove="ListBox_PreviewMouseMove"
                 PreviewMouseDown="ListBox_PreviewMouseDown">
                <ListBox.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <!--<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Content="{Binding DataContext.BackgroundType, Source={x:Reference view}}">-->
                        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                            <Border>
                                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding DataContext.BackgroundType, Source={x:Reference view}}">
                                    <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:GridBackType}">
                                            <Border>
                                                <Border.Background>
                                                <VisualBrush TileMode="Tile" Viewport="{Binding DataContext.GridSize, Source={x:Reference view}}" 
                                                             ViewportUnits="Absolute" Viewbox="0,0,50,50" ViewboxUnits="Absolute">
                                                    <VisualBrush.Visual>
                                                        <Rectangle Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="1" Height="50" Width="50"
                                                                   StrokeDashArray="5 3">
                                                        </Rectangle>
                                                    </VisualBrush.Visual>
                                                </VisualBrush>
                                            </Border.Background>
                                                <ItemsPresenter/>
                                            </Border>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ContentPresenter.Resources>
                                </ContentPresenter>
                            </Border>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </ListBox.Template>
                <ListBox.ItemsSource>
                    <StaticResource ResourceKey="Col"/>
                </ListBox.ItemsSource>
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Canvas IsItemsHost="True" Background="#01FFFFFF" 
                            Height="{Binding AreaHeight}" Width="{Binding AreaWidth}"
                            VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}"/>
                        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource EmptyFocusVisualStyle}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content"/>
                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                            <Setter TargetName="Content" Property="Effect">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <DropShadowEffect Color="Gray" ShadowDepth="4" BlurRadius="10"/>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </Trigger>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsNew}" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value=".5"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ListBox>
```

And the code for the BackgroundType class:

```
namespace NodesEditor
{
public abstract class BackgroundTypes : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public class ImageBackType : BackgroundTypes { }
public class GridBackType : BackgroundTypes { }
}
```

Comment: I think I've seen this XAML before... I just can't remember where....

Comment: LOL... I figured you were going to say something like that. Looks like whoever wrote it new what they were doing...

Comment: Your current markup doesn't work because you're messing with the `ItemsPresenter`, you must leave that where it was, and use a separate `ContentPresenter` if you want to redefine the contents of the "Background"

Comment: Thats what I figured, can't figure out how though... Border.background doesn't have a content properties to set nor does it accept `<ContentPresenter>` as a child.

Comment: Hmm actually it looks like it must be done with a Style and fired by some Style.Trigger

Comment: What kind of property is `DataContext.BackgroundType`? can you post the code for that?

Comment: Its a derived class of inoftifyproperty changed, and also the base class for the different background types.  I'll post it though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `Grid` to place the `ItemsPresenter` "above" (in Z-Index) of the Background panel, thus leaving the `ItemsPresenter` always in place while being able to modify the Background contents:

```
<Grid>
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding DataContext.BackgroundType, Source={x:Reference view}}">
        <ContentPresenter.Resources>
            <!-- etc -->
        </ContentPresenter.Resources>
    </ContentPresenter>
    <ItemsPresenter/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: That a nifty little trick bro... much easier than going through all this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965427/wpf-set-border-background-in-trigger