# WPF ControlTemplate bindings and triggers

Tags: .net, wpf, triggers, binding

I've defined this style :

```xml
<Style x:Key="ButtonIcon" TargetType="{x:Type local:ButtonIcon}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ButtonIcon}">
                    <Path x:Name="IconPath" Stretch="Uniform" Height="10" Margin="5"
                          Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IconFill}" 
                          Stroke="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IconStroke}" 
                          Data="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IconData}" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                <Setter Property="IconFill" Value="Transparent"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>        
    </Style>
```

which is basically a button with a path as content and where I've defined new properties `IconFill`, `IconStroke` and `IconData`.

Here is the `ButtonIcon` class:

```vb
Public Class ButtonIcon
    Inherits Button
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Public Sub New()
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(GetType(ButtonIcon), New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(GetType(ButtonIcon)))
    End Sub

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property IconFillProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IconFill", GetType(Brush), GetType(ButtonIcon), New UIPropertyMetadata(Brushes.Transparent))

    Public Property IconFill As Brush
        Get
            Return GetValue(IconFillProperty)
        End Get
        Set(value As Brush)
            SetValue(IconFillProperty, value)
            NotifyPropertyChanged()
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property IconStrokeProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IconStroke", GetType(Brush), GetType(ButtonIcon), New UIPropertyMetadata(Brushes.Transparent))

    Public Property IconStroke As Brush
        Get
            Return GetValue(IconStrokeProperty)
        End Get
        Set(value As Brush)
            SetValue(IconStrokeProperty, value)
            NotifyPropertyChanged()
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property IconDataProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IconData", GetType(Geometry), GetType(ButtonIcon), New UIPropertyMetadata())

    Public Property IconData As Geometry
        Get
            Return GetValue(IconDataProperty)
        End Get
        Set(value As Geometry)
            SetValue(IconDataProperty, value)
            NotifyPropertyChanged()
        End Set
    End Property

    Protected Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(<CallerMemberName> Optional propertyName As String = "")
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
    End Sub
End Class
```

and usage:

```xml
<local:ButtonIcon x:Name="BtColor1" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonIcon}" 
        IconFill="{Binding MediaColor1.FillBrush}" 
        IconStroke="{Binding MediaColor1.StrokeBrush}" 
        IconData="{DynamicResource Icons.Circle}"  />
```

Everything is as expected except that when the button is pressed, the Path Fill color doesn't become transparent.
As the Path Fill property is directly bind to the button `IconFill` I don't understand where is the error.
I've also tried to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on `ButtonIcon` class but without success.

Lastly I know that `IsPressed` trigger is working because if I change background value to some visible color I correctly see that color when I press the button.

Comment: Show us the class and property declarations. As a note, you would usually use TemplateBindings like `Fill="{TemplateBinding IconFill}"`.

Comment: @Clemens, I've edited with class definition. I would be happy to see if you have a solution with trigger into style. I'll change with `TemplateBinding`, thanks for the trick.

Comment: First of all, the INotifyPropertyChanged implementation is pointless. Please remove that.

Comment: The reason why the Style Trigger is not working is that you have directly set the IconFill property when you use the ButtonIcon. This so-called local value has higher precedence than the value set in the Setter of the Style Trigger, which is hence ignored. Use ControlTemplate Triggers, as suggested in the answer. See for reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635018/datatrigger-not-firing/1636236#1636236, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965427/wpf-set-border-background-in-trigger/3965469#3965469, https://stackoverflow.com/a/7126401/1136211

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving your triggers into the `ControlTemplate` and reference the component's name in the setters.

My `ButtonIcon.xaml` file:

```xml
<Style x:Key="ButtonIcon" TargetType="{x:Type local:ButtonIcon}">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
  <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
  <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
  <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ButtonIcon}" >
      <Border Name="Border"
              Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
              BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
              BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
              CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}">
              
          <Path Name="IconPath" Stretch="Uniform" Height="10" Margin="5"
                  Fill="{TemplateBinding IconFill}" 
                  Stroke="{TemplateBinding IconStroke}" 
                  Data="{TemplateBinding IconData}" >
          </Path>
              
      </Border>
            
      <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
              <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
          </Trigger>
          <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
              <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
              <Setter TargetName="IconPath" Property="Fill" Value="Red" />
              <Setter TargetName="IconPath" Property="Stroke" Value="Red" />
          </Trigger>
      </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
              
      </ControlTemplate>
  </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ButtonIcon}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ButtonIcon}" />
```

Usage:

```xml
<local:ButtonIcon Width="100" Height="50" 
                    BorderThickness="1" 
                    Background="#2F2F2F" 
                    CornerRadius="5" 
                    BorderBrush="DimGray"
                    IconFill="#48A999"
                    IconStroke="#48A999"
                    IconData="M9.4 16.6L4.8 12l4.6-4.6L8 6l-6 6 6 6 1.4-1.4zm5.2 0l4.6-4.6-4.6-4.6L16 6l6 6-6 6-1.4-1.4z" 
                    Cursor="Hand">
</local:ButtonIcon>
```

The component:

[image: Icon Button]

The component when moused over and pressed:

[image: Moused Over & Pressed]

- Note, I wrapped the `Path` in a `Border` and changed the trigger colors just to see it better on the UI while trying it out.

Here's the `ButtonIcon.cs` class file I used for the example:

```cs
public class ButtonIcon : Button
{
    static ButtonIcon()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ButtonIcon), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ButtonIcon)));
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
    }

    #region Dependency Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// The button's corner radius.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CornerRadiusProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(CornerRadius), 
            typeof(CornerRadius), typeof(ButtonIcon), new PropertyMetadata(new CornerRadius(0)));
        
    public CornerRadius CornerRadius
    {
        get => (CornerRadius)GetValue(CornerRadiusProperty);
        set => SetValue(CornerRadiusProperty, value);
    }   
        
        
    /// <summary>
    /// The icon's fill color.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IconFillProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(IconFill), 
            typeof(Brush), typeof(ButtonIcon), new PropertyMetadata(Brushes.Black));

    public Brush IconFill
    {
        get => (Brush)GetValue(IconFillProperty);
        set => SetValue(IconFillProperty, value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The icon's stroke color.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IconStrokeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(IconStroke), 
            typeof(Brush), typeof(ButtonIcon), new PropertyMetadata(Brushes.Black));

    public Brush IconStroke
    {
        get => (Brush)GetValue(IconStrokeProperty);
        set => SetValue(IconStrokeProperty, value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The icon's path data.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IconDataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(IconData),
            typeof(Geometry), typeof(ButtonIcon), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public Geometry IconData
    {
        get => (Geometry)GetValue(IconDataProperty);
        set => SetValue(IconDataProperty, value);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Correct property declarations should also make the Style Triggers work. There is no need to move the Triggers to the ControlTemplate. You may also write TemplateBindings instead of the lengthy TemplatedParent expressions.

Comment: @Clemens You're right about the TemplateBindings, I used what he provided to come up with the solution and completely overlooked that, however the TemplateBindings are surprisingly not working for the IconData property while I'm testing it out right now. The style triggers also weren't working properly. Is there a specific issue with moving the triggers into the ControlTemplate or is it just preference? Genuine question, in case there is an issue with it.

Comment: The IconData type must be Geometry. There is no automatic type conversion with TemplateBindings. ControlTemplate Triggers are something different than Style Triggers. They do not set the control's properties, but just that of an element in the Template.

Comment: @Clemens oh right, good catch

Comment: Thanks it's working, but I don't know why if I replace `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IconFill}` by `{TemplateBinding IconFill}` I have a compilation error "MC2000 impossible to find static member 'IconFillProperty' in 'ButtonIcon' type".